# java web application, check if any request taking more than certain amount of time

Tags: java, profiling, monitoring

I am not sure if this is the proper platform for this type of question.

I am working on a Java web application which use JPA(with play framwork) in backend and frontend html, jquery. For some requests the system is taking more than required time, some requests are taking more than 20 sec.

My question is, is there a tool or a way to identify the requests/thread which are taking more than a specified amount of time.

Thank you.

**EDIT** : I was looking for a tool which can be used long term in production server not an eclipse profiler.

Comment: JVisualVM, jconsole which makes to look up the JAVA remote applications taking how much time per method. JProfiler is another tool with can be added to eclipse to monitor the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [SIMON](http://code.google.com/p/javasimon/) in similar kind of situation. 
Edit: Yes, it does have a nice [web console](http://code.google.com/p/javasimon/wiki/WebConsole)

Comment: Thanks. +1 for your answer. I am looking for something like this. Does it generate report. I am checking this but just thought of asking you if you know.

Answer (score 1):

For measuring the performance of any request on a Java Web app, you may use a filter, like on this example:

http://blog.actuanceconsulting.com/servlet-filter-java-performance-logging/

For measuring the performance of any method, you may use `System.currentTimeMillis` embedded on the method, but it would be better if you use an aspect, to decouple time measures from business code. Also, you can remove it and add it by configuration. For more information, take a look at this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

In case the database connection is the cause, you may set a timeout on the connection.

I would also suggest you to take a look at perf4j:

http://perf4j.codehaus.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to do it in production server. A tool that can be used long term and can give me proper report about what request/thread took more than certain time.

Comment: The above approach can do exactly that. +1

Comment: @NickJ - I may have not understood it correctly, but just to confirm, are you saying, I should go to each controller function and add System.currentTimeMillis.

Comment: No. Use a filter, or an aspect, or perf4j (Ordered by complexity and functionality, from less to more)

Comment: @Andres - I am using Play framework. I dont think I have the option of filter. :( checking aspect or perf4j

Comment: I don't know much of Play, but a filter should work on any JEE app.

Comment: I've never used Play, but a quick google search on 'play framework interceptor' showed me this: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaInterceptors which might be of use.